# Error deploying node js app onto Cloudbees ClickStart

Tags: node.js, cloudbees

I'm trying to deploy a node app onto the [Cloudbees ClickStart](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/NodeJS).

I've create a node js ClickStart (this creates the jenkins job, git repository and application container).

Zipped up my app, then deployed using the Cloudbees SDK.

```
bees app:deploy -t nodejs -a nodeshort -v nodeshort.zip
```

When I try to access the URL the application is deployed on I get a 502 Bad Gateway.

Checking the application logs, I see the following printed multiple times:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/mnt/e1/genapp-apps/660f9784/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

What has caused this? More importantly, what can I do to resolve it? I've tried trashing the clickstart and recreating, but I get the same outcome each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way in which you zip the file is important.

zip -r ../myapp.zip * => WORKS FINE

zip -r myapp.zip myapp/* => DOES NOT WORK

nodejs stack expect a "main.js" script to be present in application rootdir.

You have [this](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/nodejs-clickstart) nodejs ClickStart working. Maybe you should compare your code with the ClickStart.